# Link URLs (with JSessionID) truncated during URL rewriting

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket, wicket-1.5

A user's first visit to my app's home page via a visit to

```
http://[My domain]
```

results in a URL of the form

```
http://[My domain]/main/PageHome;jsessionid=v_qqIGVQlKBbkNSOcHkAQw?0
```

That's fine, but each link on my home page has the URL of the form

```
http://[My domain]/main/..;jsessionid=v_qqIGVQlKBbkNSOcHkAQw?0-1.ILinkListener-lnkAbout
```

(of length 102 characters for the particular "About us" link URL copied here). These URLs are invalid, because of the two dots present instead of `PageHome` to complete the path properly.

Is there any way I can configure GAE/J to suppress this URL abbreviation, or is this operation the province of the web framework?

As a (pretty poor) work-around, I have already coded the supression of JSessionIDs in my links' URLs, and am coding the app to give a warning if session cookies are disabled. But I would appreciate any pointers.

Ian Marshall

### My operating environment

Web application server: GAE/J 1.6.1.1 (not dev server) (I know: it's not the latest version)

Web framework: Apache Wicket 1.5.3

Web browsers producing the above effect:

  ·  Mozilla Firefox 10.0.1

  ·  Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702

  ·  as found on my HTC Wildfire S running Google Android 2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. Fixed it by overriding newWebRequest in my application class with this:

```
protected WebRequest newWebRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
        String filterPath) {
    WebRequest webRequest = super.newWebRequest(servletRequest, filterPath);
    return new ServletWebRequest(servletRequest, filterPath, webRequest.getUrl().canonical());
}
```

Comment: There is also a patch by Martin Grigorov available [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4401)

Answer (score 0):

Ian, some sample code to recreate the problem would be helpful..

Comment: In my opinion, no special sample code is needed. The simple action of visiting a Wicket WebPage running in GAE/J yields the above URLs for me (for the versions of the frameworks and environment I listed). Any existing Wicket web application (with my framework and environment versions) which shows a page descended from WebPage should show what I now get.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by going around it.

All my web pages are descended from my PageBase class, which in turn descends from Wicket's WebPage.

·  I disable my automatic removal of JSessionID by ceasing to override in my WebApplication

```
  public String ServletWebResponse.encodeURL(CharSequence url)
```

·  In my PageBase constructor, I determine whether (session) cookies are detected as being stored or not.

·  If not, then I raise an

```
  org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseException(final Class<C> pageClass)
```

to show my PageCookiesDisabled. This interrupts a "Not found" error from an invalid URL containing ".." characters, which I encountered previously.